# Not loading wp7 designer on visual studio

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Problem with wp7 emulator on visual studio. When I  try to reload designer it gives me "The given key was not present in the dictionary" error.It error gives on every page, even on new created, but designer correct work on other projects, so how i understand the problem is with some properties of the project, please help me.

Comment: You have everything installed correctly... you have the developer kit for wp7?

Comment: @ Ivan Crojach Karačić Yes, and it works correctly on other projects, so I think this error from some properties of this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i too Recently got this error on every project, i downloaded and made sure i had service pack 1.

If it continues i would re install the Wp7 Tools, as that was my ultimate answer.

Comment: i have this error only on one project, others work fine, and i have sp1

Comment: are you loading it in Blend 4? if so see what the error is there, that will deal with more XAMl results. may help you with the error, if its not loading i believe it to be the XAMl somewhere.

Comment: all design is done in the XAML code, like before i would load it into Blend and see what errors you get there.